# How can I make my js script run as more items are added to a list?

Tags: javascript

I am using Fraudio.js to replace the html5 audio player in the browser.  I am also using another pagination plug-in to lazy load items to the page as you scroll.   My issue is that the audio player script is only affecting the items that are initially loaded to the page, but not the items that are added to the page as you scroll.

Is there something I can run that will watch the list for newly added items, then run the audio player script i'm using on all the new items?

More specifically, if I could make the audio player script simply look for any audio tags that get created at any time anywhere on the page and automatically run on them at the time they do that would work just fine.

Comment: You could use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes to the dom, or just a regular old event listener with a custom event. Do you have an example of your code? A [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help you get answers.